# Year part update in SQL Server DateTime column

Tags: sql-server, datetime

[image: Table_Data]

I need to change only the year part of every `ChangedDate` column value to 2017.

For example:

```
2017-02-08 13:55:30.193   
2017-02-08 13:55:30.193  
2017-02-08 13:55:30.193
```

Comment: what database you are using?

Comment: Sql Server 2016

Answer (score 1):

you can update all your data column with DATEADD() function

```
update t1
    set update_at = t2.update_now
    from (select id,DATEADD(year, 1,update_at ) as update_now from t1) as t2
    where t1.id = t2.id
select * from t1;
```

Comment: What's the point of having the subquery? Why not just have 

``update t1 set ChangedDate = DATEADD(year, 1, ChangedDate)``

Comment: Overly complex but the general approach of using dateadd for the year difference is simpler. The addition of a where clause to ignore rows within the 2017 year would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DateCol datetime = '2020-02-08 13:55:30.193'

SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar(50), DATEPART(YYYY,'2017-02-08')) + '-' +
    CONVERT(varchar(50), DATEPART(mm, @DateCol)) + '-' +
    CONVERT(varchar(50), DATEPART(dd, @DateCol)) + ' ' +
    CONVERT(char(12), CAST(@DateCol AS TIME))
```

Output

```
2017-2-8 13:55:30.193
```

[Read more about it here](http://www.csharpmonster.com/BlogDetails.aspx?BlogId=120&name=Year-Part-Update-in-sql-DateTime-Column)

Comment: If the original uses two digits for day and month, I'd expect the result to **also** use two digits for day (`08` - not just `8`) and month.....

Comment: cast to varchar(50)?  just lazy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use the `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` function - seems the cleanest way, without converting every `DATETIME` to a string and then fiddling around with snipping up and glueing together a string again and converting back to `DATETIME`....

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    Id, ChangedDate,

    DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2017, MONTH(ChangedDate), DAY(ChangedDate), 
                      DATEPART(HOUR, ChangedDate), DATEPART(MINUTE, ChangedDate), 
                      DATEPART(SECOND, ChangedDate), DATEPART(MILLISECOND, ChangedDate))
FROM 
    dbo.YourTableNameHere
```